# Codigo de error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

PROBLEMA/ERROR

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /
>   core/index.html
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Django Version: 3.0.4
>   Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
>   Exception Value:
>   core/index.html
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto\django\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.8.0
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto',
>    'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto',
>    'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm '
>    '2019.3\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm_display',
>    'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip',
>    'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib',
>    'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32',
>    'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto\django',
>    'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto\django\lib\site-packages',
>    'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto\django\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg',
>    'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Proyecto_Reto\django\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg',
>    'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm '
>    '2019.3\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
>   Server time:    Lun, 30 Mar 2020 19:41:25 +0000

CODIGO

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<section class="portada">
    <div class="textos">
           <h1 class="titulo"><font face="Candara">Chiquimundi</h1></script>
            <h2>Hacemos que tus experiencias sean únicas</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="{% url 'index.html' %}" class="boton">Reserva Aquí</a>
     </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Django no encontró el template `index.html`, debe ir dentro de la carpeta `templates` que debe estar dentro de tu aplicación o proyecto.

Comment: @JulioCesar si gracias ya lo pude resolver, el problema era que estaba mal declarado mi directorio template, y era *templates*.

Comment: Ok no hay de que. :)